# Fill in area between two lines in Area chart, where I have 3 lines represented in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to adjust my area chart that currently represents 3 lines to fill in with color between two of the lines. I changed transparency to 0% for the top line. The shading for the 2nd line extends all the way to the x axis and so does the last. Here is my script creating the chart...

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SPREADSHEET NAME'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asAreaChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'DATA\'!B3:B15'))
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'DATA\'!I3:K15'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
   .setNumHeaders(-1)
  .setBackgroundColor('#f9f9f9')
  .setOption('legend.position', 'bottom')
  .setOption('title', 'TITLE')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.fontSize', 14)
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.bold', false)
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.alignment', 'center')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('hAxis.slantedText', true)
  .setOption('hAxis.slantedTextAngle', 0)
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.fontSize', 10)
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.fontSize', 10)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('series.0.color', '#b4a7d6')
  .setOption('series.1.areaOpacity', 0)
  .setOption('width', 807)
  .setPosition(29, 10.9, 26, 19)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

[My chart and what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdox8.png)

[New chart after suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUB0G.png)

[New chart after suggestions_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUB0G.png)

Comment: Not really. I added a screenshot of my chart (above in my original post) and what i'm trying to achieve. Take a look...